# Facebook share 'clickable' url-link issue

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share, clickable

I have a problem with clickable url-link in Facebook.

[image]

As you can see nr 1. is not clickable but nr 2 and 3 are. 
Sometimes it is clickable and other times not. (randomize)

What I want is that all the share links are not 'clickable' like nr 1.

How can I fix this? I'm stuck for several days.

My php code:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<li class="icon share_facebook l" id="facebookshare"><a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.smartnet7.com/promo.php?id_promo=<?php echo $id_promo?>&username=<?php echo $username ?>"target="_blank"></a> </li>
```

I hope some body can help me!

Comment: Hi, can you provide the URLs that people shared above for each of the three?

Comment: Have you seen Facebook Linter? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the page that you are trying to share. As mentioned earlier in the comments above, you may check the same page's link by Facebook Linter. To achieve a uniformity you may want to include the Opengraph meta tags as recommended by Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

In your case it looks like an issue with Facebook populating your page url so you might want to include `<meta property="og:url" content="your page's complete url"/>` within the `<head> </head>` tags in your page. Even though this url can be determined from your page alone but Facebook recommends you to include these tags to avoid any inconsistency.

Answer (score -2):

May be number 1 isn't clickable as it is not a valid url(although browser should figure it out). It should have www. in the beginning

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; 'www' isn't a mandatory prefix for HTTP server domain names